# Capybara - how to qualify based on multiple attributes?

Tags: selenium, attributes, capybara

I can use

```
expect(page).to have_selector("label.field_with_errors")
```

and

```
expect(page).to have_selector("label[for='landing_zip_code']")
```

and they work ok.
However I want to check if they are both true on the same field.

I've tried:

```
expect(page).to
have_selector("label[class='field_with_errors']:and([for='landing_zip_code'])")
```

and

```
expect(page).to
have_selector("label[class='field_with_errors']") &&
have_selector('landing_zip_code')
```

but neither worked.
error for 2nd attempt:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to
have_selector("label[class='field_with_errors']") &&
have_selector('landing_zip_code')
expected to find css "landing_zip_code" but there were no matches
```

I also tried

```
expect(find("label[class='field_with_errors']")).to
have_attribute('for=landing_zip_code')
```

but get

```
Failure/Error: expect(find("label[class='field_with_errors']")).
to have_attribute('for=landing_zip_code')
expected #<Capybara::Node::Element:0x00003b5de90> to respond to `has_attribute?`
# ./spec/features/quote_spec.rb:65:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I tried

```
expect(find("label[class='field_with_errors']")['for=landing_zip_code']).to be
```

but get

```
Failure/Error: expect(find("label[class='field_with_errors']")['for=landing_zip_code']).to be
expected nil to evaluate to true
```

Answer (score 0):

In this (I am the OP) I can use the "`.`"class and "`#`"identifiers to do this, i.e.

```
expect(page).to
have_selector("label.field_with_errors[for='landing_zip_code']")
```

however I'd also like to know how to detect when there are other, multiple attributes aside from class and id

Comment: You can continue checking attributes in a similar way: `label.field_with_errors[for='landing_zip_code'][other_attr=value1][one_more_attr=value2]`. Is this what you are asking about? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the below?

```
expect(page).to have_selector("label[for='landing_zip_code']" && "label.field_with_errors")
```

Answer (score 0):

`expect(find("label[class='field_with_errors']['for=landing_zip_code']")).to be`

Comment: While this might answer the authors' question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.